# Correct way to apply CSS style to active state to one button but not other buttons within different class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

OK so I found the :not pseudo element and wanted to apply a style to all buttons that are active EXCEPT one within another class. This is the CSS decleration I came up with but Dreamweaver, and more importantly the browser, does not like it and voids the whole decleration...

```
.button:active:not(.success .button:active) {
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
}
```

It looks like it makes sense to me logically but is there something about all these colons which confuses CSS?

PS. Its important because the button in the 'success' class is absolutely positioned, and adding this top:4px; screws everything up there.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please pase working JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "in the 'success' class", does that mean that you have an element with the class "`success`" and the button inside it? Something like this:

```
<div class="success">
    <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

If so, `:not()` is not the selector to use. The solution is to add another class onto the button and apply your styles to that:

```
<div class="success">
    <button class="button button-success"></button>
</div>
```

and in the CSS:

```
.button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}

.button-success:active {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Correct. 'Success' is the containing div. Thanks for that, was hoping I could target it specifically but I guess not

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like

```
.button:not(.success):active {
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
}
```

as **example**: https://jsfiddle.net/nh4f821y/

```css
.button {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    float: left;
}

.button:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.button:not(.success):active {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="button success">1</div>
<div class="button success">2</div>
<div class="button">3</div>
<div class="button">4</div>
<div class="button success">5</div>

<p>On click, the background only change for divs <b>3</b> and <b>4</b></p>
```

Good Luck'

Comment: Thanks for giving me a better understanding of the :not selector, however success is the class of the parent div, I should have made that clear. Seems what I'm asking isnt possible

Comment: @bboybeatle As far as it was useful it's cool. Next time try to link you `html` as well and why not a **JsFiddle**.