# Style all buttons except 2 buttons

Tags: html, css, button, border

```
.button , button{
border:solid black 2px !important;
}
```

With this code I have provided a frame for all buttons. However, I don't want to have a frame for the buttons "searchsubmit" and "single_add_to_cart_button". How do I do that ?

Comment: you can over write the style for that button only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747104/correct-way-to-apply-css-style-to-active-state-to-one-button-but-not-other-butto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe those are your class names. If yes, then you can add border: none !important.

```
button.searchsubmit, 
button.single_add_to_cart_button {
   border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This will overwrite the user agent stylesheet and cause the button to have no border at all!

Answer (score 2):

It is not that difficult.

There are two ways ways for that first is simpler and is recommended!

```
.noBorderButton{
      border : none !important;
}
```

and in your HTML you can add the class "noBorderButton" to your buttons.

```
<button class="noBorderButton">Search Submit</button>
```

P.S. Make sure to follow the CSS overwriting rules i.e. write the .noBorderButton CSS below the Button CSS.

EDIT : As I can see Martin suggesting this will change the user agent styling and button won't have any Border at all, and probably you don't want that either!!

You may go with the Following Option

```
button:not(.noBorderButton){
border:solid black 2px !important;
}
```

And yes again add the class 'noBorderButton' to those buttons in which you don't want these styling to work.

Answer (score 1):

simply do:

Class:
`.searchsubmit {border:none;!important}` and `.single_add_to_cart_button {border:none;!important}`

Id:
`#searchsubmit {border:none;!important}` and `#single_add_to_cart_button {border:none;!important}`

It can be cleaner but this works to... :)

Comment: This will overwrite the user agent stylesheet and cause the button to have no border at all!

Comment: @Martin that's what he wants? He doesn't want it to have a border at all.

Comment: what OP actually said was _I don't want to have a frame_.  The code you have provided will remove the border completely from the buttons rather than removing the black border

Answer (score 1):

you can use the not css selector

```
.button , button:not(.searchsubmit):not(.single_add_to_cart_button) {
   border:solid black 2px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, you can use :not selector to ignore those two button having your specific classes :

```
.button , button , button:not('single_add_to_cart_button') , button:not('searchsubmit') {
border:solid black 2px !important;
}
```

or you can do it from a reverse way which i do not recommend, its like you set a border to a button and then you unset it :

```
button.searchsubmit , button.single_add_to_cart_button {
   border: none !important;
}
```

(ofcourse the style above must be after your .button and button style in-order to override it)